# Need help figuring why I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am still learning the pdo and php in general, I am creating a CRUD from a tutorial and converting the mysql into PDO but am getting the following two errors and am not quite sure why. The errors occur when I am testing out the update part of the code using a specific "find_by_id" method in user.php. Without the method updating into mysql works fine.

When I run find_by_id it in turn runs find_by_sql which also runs instantiate and has_attributes. I var_dumped $found from find_by_sql and get the following:

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [username] => bingo
    [password] => 123
    [first_name] => bingo
    [last_name] => bongo
)

**Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 20**

**Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 21**

**Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 22**

**Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 23**

**Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 24**

**Fatal error:  Call to a member function update() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 25**

I have the code broken out into the database.php, user.php and test.php. Any help would be appreciated and to further my learning.

**database.php**

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."db_config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

private $dbh;
public $last_query;
public $stmt;

function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
}

public function open_connection() {
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->message;
        exit;
    }
}

public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default: 
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute() {
return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

**user.php (extends the database class)**

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php");

class User extends MYSQLDatabase {

protected static $table_name = "users";
public $id;
public $username; 
public $password; 
public $first_name; 
public $last_name; 

public static function find_by_id($id) {
    global $database;

    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name . " WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1");

    return $result_array;
}

public static function find_by_sql($sql = "") {
    global $database;

    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    $row2 = $database->resultset();
    while ($row = array_shift($row2)) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "<hr />";
        echo "<br />";
    }
    return $object_array;
}

private static function instantiate($record) { 
    $object = new self;

    foreach ($record as $attribute => $value) {
        if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}

private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    // get_object_vars returns an associate array with all attributes
    // including private ones as the keys and their current values as the value
    $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);

    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
}

public function update() {
    global $database;

    $sql  = "UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = ?, first_name = ?, last_name = ?
             WHERE id = ?";
    $database->query($sql);
    $database->bind(1, $this->username);
    $database->bind(2, $this->password);
    $database->bind(3, $this->first_name);
    $database->bind(4, $this->last_name);
    $database->bind(5, $this->id);
    $database->execute();
    return ($database->lastInsertId() == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

**test.php**

```
    <?php
require_once("../../includes/initialize.php");

if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); }
?>


<?php include_layout_template("admin_header.php"); ?>
    <?php
        // Create
        $user = new User();
        // $user->username   = "test01";    
        // $user->password   = "1234";
        // $user->first_name = "test";
        // $user->last_name  = "test";
        // $user->create();

        // Update
        $user->find_by_id(6);

        $user->username   = "bingo";
        // $user->password   = "123";
        // $user->first_name = "bingo";
        // $user->last_name  = "bongo";
        // $user->id          = "7";
        $user->update();
    ?>
<?php include_layout_template("admin_footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: check if class User contains method update() or not with get_class_method() function.

reference : http://us1.php.net/get_class_methods

Comment: If I am not mistaken your find_by_id method is calling the find_by_sql which in turns returns an array, not an User object. You are trying to call the update() method on an array.

Comment: Right, then from the find_by_sql it gets instantiated. When I do a var dump $found (find_by_sql) I get this: stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [username] => bingo
    [password] => 123
    [first_name] => bingo
    [last_name] => bongo
)

Comment: And yes the class User does contain update() when checking with get_class_method().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything else in your code is working the way it should, then the reason this isn't working is because your `User::find_by_id(6)`function call is returning an array that *contains* the object you want, not the object itself. That array has no "update" method, since arrays do not have methods, even though they may contain objects that *do* have methods.

If I'm reading your code correctly, the object you want lives at the 0th index of that array. 
So try returning `$result_array[0]` from that `get_by_id()` function instead of just `$result_array`.

Comment: Tried you suggestion with changing $result_array[0], however I'm not getting the error anymore but it's still not updating the field when I use the find_by_id method.

Comment: Ah, that's a separate problem from before. There are a couple problems I can see. One is that you shouldn't be doing `$sql .= $database->query() ...` etc for all those database methods. Try just doing `$database->query(); $database->bind(); ...$database->execute()` instead. When you do `$sql .= $database->query();", you're actually just appending the return value of those method calls to your `$sql` string - which you don't need to touch anymore since you've already set it as `$database->query()`. But in theory that shouldn't actually prevent the $database object from running its methods.

Comment: The second thing, and this is likely your actual problem, is that when you call the update method, you are trying to change the `id` of the database row you are attempting to update - from `6` to `7`. Look at your update query - it's looking to update a row `WHERE id = ?`. So it's looking for a row with an `id` of `7`, but that row doesn't exist yet.   When you update something, you don't want to change the `id`, the DB uses the ID to determine which row to update. If you use a new ID, you are *creating* a new row. So I'd say for now just comment out `$user->id = "7";` and you should be fine.

Comment: @patricksayhi - Tried your advice by removing the $sql .= and just used $database->etc. and commented out the changing of the id. I don't get errors anymore but it doesn't update either. (Updated the user.php and test.php code above to reflect the changes)

Comment: Hmm. Another thing I'm seeing now is that when you run `$user->find_by_id(6)`, you're not actually storing the return value of that function anywhere. So `$user` isn't actually changed, and as a result it doesn't have its `id` property set. You could do something like overwriting the original value of `$user` by just doing `$user = $user->find_by_id(6)`. Or since `find_by_id` is a static function, it also looks like you could initialize `$user` like this: `$user = User::find_by_id(6);` Maybe that will get you where you ned to go?

Comment: @patricksayhi - looks like removing the .sql, $user=User::find_by_id and using $result_array[0] did the trick, it updates now. whew... thanks mate you're a life-saver. Can you explain why $result_array[0] works and not just $result_array?

Answer (score 1):

your function

```
 public static function find_by_id($id)
 {
   global $database;

   $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name . " WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1");

   return $result_array;
 }
```

returns array instead it should return self object to call another function

Comment: Right but find_by_id runs find_by_sql which turns it into a stdClass Object when I var_dump $found from find_by_sql.

Comment: try returning $row2 from find_by_sql

Comment: var_dump: $row2 is an Array
(
) var_dump: $row is stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [username] => bingo
    [password] => 123
    [first_name] => bingo
    [last_name] => bongo
)

Comment: then try changing $object to $database in instantiate function

Comment: Swapped $object to $database in the method instantiate to no avail, obviously switching it out in (a)$object = new self, (b) in the if statement and (c) return $object gives me the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of using OOP is misleading.

User::find_by_id(); does not return a User object.

You can not call assign User attributes(username,password ...) to an array.